# Atom change default treeview and editor context menus

Tags: contextmenu, atom-editor

I'm playing around with the Atom text editor. I've looked around in the config but I don't see anywhere I can edit the default context menu for the file tree and editor.

I would like to get rid of options such as: cut, copy, paste, and select all. They bloat up my menus, and I always use the keyboard anyways.

How can I remove items from Atom's context menus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's hack Atom!

Atom stores context menu options for the editor in `atom.contextMenu.itemSets`. All we need to do is loop through this array on startup and remove the elements we don't want.

Add this to your init script (`Edit` -> `Open Your Init Script`):

```coffeescript
# itemsToRemove contains commands to remove organized by menu selector
itemsToRemove = {
    'atom-text-editor, .overlayer': [
        'core:cut',
        'core:copy',
        'core:paste',
        'core:select-all',
    ],
    '.tree-view.full-menu': [
        'tree-view:cut',
        'tree-view:copy',
        'tree-view:paste',
    ],
}

menus = atom.contextMenu.itemSets

for menu in menus
    if !itemsToRemove[menu.selector]
        # This is not the menu we're looking for
        continue

    items = menu.items
    evilItems = itemsToRemove[menu.selector]
    i = items.length

    # Loop backwards because we're changing the array we're looping through
    while i--
        item = items[i]

        # Is it an evil item?
        if evilItems.indexOf(item.command) > -1
            console.log 'Removing: ' + item.label + ' >> ' + item.command
            # Die, evil item, DIE!
            items.splice(i, 1)
```